# How to fix the tf.app.run() bug with app not recognized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I started to learn tensorflow with the tutorial on their official website (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining). I followed the steps by understanding them and I'm stuck at this point.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrain.py", line 1349, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'app'
```

You can find the retrain.py file in the following link (https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).

I searched in forums, and all questions was about the args. None of them were about the tf.app.run function itself. So I read this function (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py#L31-L48), and I didn't found my answer there.

Should I replace this line, by something else instead?

I don't know if this (official) tutorial is deprecated, I don't think so.
By the way, if you have some good tutorials to recommend, I would love to do them.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 2.0 was released recently, all the v1 modules are deprecated.

You must have installed the latest tensorflow either downgrade the tensorflow version

`pip3 install tensorflow==1.15.0`

or

Find `tf.` in retrain.py and replace all occurrences with `tf.compat.v1.`